# Error converting data type DBTYPE_DBDATE to date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, load

I am trying to load data from file to SQL Server Express, using this command:

```
BULK INSERT Clients_test FROM 'c:\clints_aa.csv'
    WITH ( KEEPIDENTITY, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

But I get this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 10, Line 2
>   
> Error converting data type DBTYPE_DBDATE to date.

Sample data:

```
1,F,L,E,1950-12-18,x,-,z,6,k,r,4,1,N,1,m,,3,5,o,3,0,0,0,0,1,,,1900-01-01,1900-01-01,-
2,O,L,F,1946-06-23,y,-,z,6,l,s,5,0,N,1,n,,1,7,p,1,0,1,1,0,4,,,1900-01-01,1900-01-01,-
```

Columns which contain dates are the 5th and 2 before the last column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you attempt to insert your date time values as a string, you need to convert them to DATETIME in T-SQL:

```
CONVERT('2013-02-26 16:51:23.767', GETDATE(), 126)
```

This is using normal T-SQL, and does not take into consideration the bulk insert.  If you want to use bulk insert, it would help if you had Visual Studio Business Intelligence Development Studio. For details please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767.aspx.

Comment: I am loading data from text file there is more than 8000 records I dont wanna modify them by hands. Or I should add convert line into my loading statement?

Comment: You could download Visual Studio Express for C# and/or Visual Basic and write a little program to read the records in and then perform the CONVERT in the C# code.  Here is a great article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361579/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-ADO-NET

Comment: this not solution. I used to be able load same data with out one field and it was loading perfectly, but than i add one more row with date and it start trowing me error

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm not sure how to solve your problem without Business Intelligence Development Studio.  Perhaps this link on bulk insert could help you with your problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: I solve it by modifying date format in my csv file. Just simply set  date in this format 1950-05-18 00:00:00

Comment: Great, glad to hear you got is sorted out!

Comment: I've run into an issue like this importing a medical billing file.  I made a temp table using all varchar data types on fields I was unsure about.  I would run a SP to "copy" from the temp table, truncate it, and format the data as I inserted it into it's perm record.  It was not a perfect implementation but performance wasn't as bad as one might think.  Bulk Insert is very nice when you can use it.

Comment: but  for doing that I have to have data in Db but my data was in text file which was created from assecc db :) . But thanx will try if will have problem like this again